# Is there a way to define a global var within a twig block?

Tags: templating, blocks, extends, scope, set

Something that would work like this:

```
{% block A %}
  {% set testVar = "foo" %}
{% endblock %}
...
{% block B %}
  {{ testVar }}
{% endblock %}
```

The scope of `testVar` seems limited to `{% block A %}`

I'm looking for a way around this, so that the child template can pass content to the parent to use in other blocks.

This is an issue since the child template that extends the parent cannot have content outside a defined block.

Comment: Why not set the variable outside of the blocks? It should be usable in both then.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Twig variables are only accessible inside their own scope.

.

**What is a scope:**

Tags like `{% block %}`, `{% for %}`, `{% nav %}` create a 'scope', which means that variables defined inside them, can't be accessed from outside. This is similar to [local variables inside php-functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

```
{% block A %}
    {% set var = 'apple' %}
    {{ var }} {# This prints apple #}
{% endblock %}

{% block B %}
    {{ var }} {# This doesn't prints anything, since var isn't defined #}
{% endblock %}
```

.

**Variables outside their scope:**

To make variables accessible outside their scope you have to [define them before](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html):

```
{% set var = 'apple' %}  

{% block A %}
    {{ var }} {# This prints apple #}
{% endblock %}

{% block B %}
    {% set var = 'banana' %}
    {{ var }} {# This prints banana #}
{% endblock %}

{% block A %}
    {{ var }} {# This prints banana #}
{% endblock %}
```

.

Answer (score 4):

This article may help as well: [Twig Processing Order & Scope](https://nystudio107.com/blog/twig-processing-order-and-scope)

Comment: Link only questions are strongly discouraged. Please add more information in your answer or add the link as a comment.