# How do I pass an image to the _layout

Tags: templating

I'm trying to send a meta-data image from an entry template to the main layout template.  The image is in a matrix block on the entry.  It comes out correctly when I call it on the entry page, but when I try to pass it to the layout it doesn't see it and reverts to the default image called in the layout.  Any help is appreciated

_Layout template

```
<meta property="twitter:image:src" content={% if twitterpic is defined %}"{{ twitterpic }}"{%else%}"{{ siteImage.getUrl('twitterPic') }}" {%endif%}/>
```

_entry template

```
{#  social image  #}
{% for block in entry.projectImage%}
{% set image for block.projectImage.first() %}
{% set twitterpic =image.getUrl('twitterPic') %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/153/177

Comment: Hi @Micah, and welcome to the Craft CMS Stack Exchange site! As Victor In pointed out, a similar question has already been asked and answered here. You might also find [this question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/859/how-do-i-add-an-html-block-from-template-extension-to-main-layout-template-i-e/860#860) on passing meta tags useful.

Comment: I'm in the same block, and all my other variables are passing fine.  That's not the problem.  The problem seems to be specific to the asset call

Comment: @MicahMorgan As the linked answer indicates, this is a scope issue. You're defining `twitterpic` within your foor loop, but you first need to define it *outside the loop* if you want it to be available elsewhere. You're also running `.getUrl('twitterPic')` twice. You should either pass the asset (`image`) or pass the URL reference (`twitterpic`).

Comment: thank you for the clarification.  I read it all, but it didn't sink in

Comment: @MicahMorgan "I read it all, but it didn't sink in" explains most of the problems I have :)